# Read Only Class Variables (C++) and Operator Overloading

Tags: c++, templates, operator-keyword

Take the following code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template <class T, class U>
class readonly
{
  friend U;
  private:
    T data;
    T operator=(const T& arg) {data = arg; return data;}
    T operator+=(const T& arg) {data = data + arg; return data;}
    T operator-=(const T& arg) {data = data - arg; return data;}
    T operator*=(const T& arg) {data = data * arg; return data;}
    T operator/=(const T& arg) {data = data / arg; return data;}
  public:
    operator const T&() const {return data;}
};

class myClass
{
  private:
    typedef readonly<int, myClass> RO_int;
    typedef readonly<std::string, myClass> RO_string;

  public:
    RO_int x;
    RO_string y;

    void f()
    {
      x = 55;
      y = "Howdy";
      std::cout << x << "\n\n";  // compiles fine
      std::cout << y << "\n\n";  // compile error
    }
};
```

I'm using these template classes to make sure that certain public variables `x` and `y` are "read-only" outside of the class, but can be modified within the class itself.  Everything in this code compiles fine except the very last line where I'm trying to display the variable y which is of string type.  I don't understand why I'm able to display `x` but not `y`.  If I need to overload the `<<` operator, why do I have to do it for `std::string` but not for `int`?

Comment: This is just a header file that gets included into main.cpp.  All I'm doing in main.cpp is creating an object of myClass type and then calling function f().  Sorry, I should have made that more clear.

Comment: The output for the int one is 0, so I don't think its using the correct overload to display `x` anyway. Probably you need to overload `<<` to make it work for any type.

Comment: Seems like an awful lot of mechanism for something straightforward: `private: int x_; public: int x() const { return x_; }`.

Comment: @PeteBecker, while I agree with you, I'm just trying to avoid using the () notation, as it would force me to rewrite a lot of my code.  I also would like to avoid it to make the hundreds of places that I do access these variables much shorter.

Answer (score 3):

First, but not your question, your operators should return `readonly&` or `T&` not `T`.  Don't break convention like that.

Now for an actual answer.

It is because `operator<<` that `string` uses is a template, and template functions do not consider conversions when pattern matching.  The `<<` that takes an `int` is not a template, so it does consider conversions.

We can fix this in general by creating an `operator<<` that doesn't convert:

Simply add

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, readonly const& self)
{
  return os<<self.data;
}
```

to your `readonly` type and things should work.  This will be found via ADL.

We could make it fancier with SFINAE and the like by taking the first argument by template and checking that `<<` works and that the first argument is derived from `std::ostream`, or similarly for the second argument.